# Execution plan depends on where output columns are concatenated

Tags: oracle, optimization

This query:

```
SELECT
    em.Value ||'|'|| CAST(acc.FIRST_ACT_DATE AS DATE) ||'|'||
    null||'|'|| spt.PROD_CODE_ID
FROM
    lc_account_tbl lat
    INNER JOIN event_mapping_tbl em ON em.ACCOUNT_FK = lat.ACCOUNT_FK
    INNER JOIN account_tbl acc ON acc.ACCOUNT_ID = lat.ACCOUNT_FK
    INNER JOIN sold_component_tbl sct ON sct.ACCOUNT_FK = acc.ACCOUNT_ID
    INNER JOIN sold_product_tbl spt ON spt.SOLD_PRODUCT_ID = sct.SOLD_PRODUCT_FK
    INNER JOIN lc_sold_component_tbl lst ON sct.SOLD_COMPONENT_ID = lst.SOLD_COMPONENT_FK
WHERE
    lat.RECORD_STATE_IND = 0
    and lat.LC_STATE = 'ACT'
    and lst.RECORD_STATE_IND = 0
    and lst.LC_STATE = 'ACT'
    and em.EXT_ID_TYPE_CODE_ID = 2
    and (em.VALID_FROM is null or trunc(em.VALID_FROM) < SYSDATE)
    and sct.SOLD_COMPONENT_TYPE = 'UTF'
    and spt.sold_product_name like 'T_%'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    em.Value ||'|'|| CAST(acc.first_act_date AS DATE) ||'|'||
    CAST(sct.first_act_date AS DATE) ||'|'|| spt.PROD_CODE_ID 
FROM
    lc_account_tbl lat
    INNER JOIN event_mapping_tbl em ON em.ACCOUNT_FK = lat.ACCOUNT_FK
    INNER JOIN account_tbl acc ON acc.ACCOUNT_ID = lat.ACCOUNT_FK
    INNER JOIN sold_component_tbl sct ON sct.ACCOUNT_FK = acc.ACCOUNT_ID
    INNER JOIN lc_sold_component_tbl lst ON sct.SOLD_COMPONENT_ID = lst.SOLD_COMPONENT_FK
    INNER JOIN sold_product_tbl spt ON spt.SOLD_PRODUCT_ID = sct.SOLD_PRODUCT_FK
WHERE lat.RECORD_STATE_IND = 0
    and lat.LC_STATE = 'PAS' and lat.LC_SUB_STATE_CODE_ID = 'LOST' 
    and lst.RECORD_STATE_IND = 0
    and lst.LC_STATE = 'PAS' and lst.LC_SUB_STATE_CODE_ID = 'STD'
    and em.EXT_ID_TYPE_CODE_ID = 2
    and (em.VALID_FROM is null or trunc(em.VALID_FROM) < SYSDATE)
    and sct.SOLD_COMPONENT_TYPE = 'UTF'
    and spt.sold_product_name like 'T_%'
```

Produces this plan:

```
Plan hash value: 539075029

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |                       | 11287 |  1411K| 35528   (2)| 00:08:18 |
|   1 |  UNION-ALL                          |                       |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                         |                       | 11274 |  1409K| 24297   (2)| 00:05:41 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN                        |                       |  9777 |  1098K| 17292   (2)| 00:04:03 |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN                       |                       |  9778 |   859K| 15871   (2)| 00:03:43 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN                      |                       | 19744 |  1311K|  9871   (2)| 00:02:19 |
|*  6 |       HASH JOIN                     |                       | 19744 |   944K|  5143   (2)| 00:01:12 |
|*  7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL            | EVENT_MAPPING_TBL     | 17199 |   604K|  1309   (4)| 00:00:19 |
|*  8 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL            | LC_ACCOUNT_TBL        |   259K|  3291K|  3832   (1)| 00:00:54 |
|   9 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL             | ACCOUNT_TBL           |   689K|    12M|  4724   (1)| 00:01:07 |
|* 10 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL              | SOLD_COMPONENT_TBL    |   341K|  7339K|  5998   (1)| 00:01:24 |
|* 11 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL               | SOLD_PRODUCT_TBL      |   345K|  8442K|  1419   (2)| 00:00:20 |
|* 12 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                | LC_SOLD_COMPONENT_TBL |   855K|    10M|  7001   (2)| 00:01:39 |
|  13 |   NESTED LOOPS                      |                       |    13 |  1963 | 11231   (1)| 00:02:38 |
|  14 |    NESTED LOOPS                     |                       |    13 |  1963 | 11231   (1)| 00:02:38 |
|  15 |     NESTED LOOPS                    |                       |    13 |  1638 | 11205   (1)| 00:02:37 |
|* 16 |      HASH JOIN                      |                       |    13 |  1170 | 11179   (1)| 00:02:37 |
|  17 |       NESTED LOOPS                  |                       |    43 |  3096 |  4179   (1)| 00:00:59 |
|  18 |        NESTED LOOPS                 |                       |   435 |  3096 |  4179   (1)| 00:00:59 |
|  19 |         NESTED LOOPS                |                       |    87 |  3219 |  3920   (1)| 00:00:55 |
|* 20 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL          | LC_ACCOUNT_TBL        |    87 |  1566 |  3833   (2)| 00:00:54 |
|  21 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| ACCOUNT_TBL           |     1 |    19 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | ACCOUNT_PK            |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 23 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN            | SC_ACCFK_IDX          |     5 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 24 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | SOLD_COMPONENT_TBL    |     1 |    35 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 25 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL             | LC_SOLD_COMPONENT_TBL |   101K|  1778K|  6999   (1)| 00:01:38 |
|* 26 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | EVENT_MAPPING_TBL     |     1 |    36 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 27 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN              | EM_ACCFK_IDX          |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 28 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | SOLD_PRODUCT_PK       |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 29 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | SOLD_PRODUCT_TBL      |     1 |    25 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SET$1       
   2 - SEL$AAE11CA2
   7 - SEL$AAE11CA2 / EM@SEL$1
   8 - SEL$AAE11CA2 / LAT@SEL$1
   9 - SEL$AAE11CA2 / ACC@SEL$2
  10 - SEL$AAE11CA2 / SCT@SEL$3
  11 - SEL$AAE11CA2 / SPT@SEL$4
  12 - SEL$AAE11CA2 / LST@SEL$5
  13 - SEL$6C998BA3
  20 - SEL$6C998BA3 / LAT@SEL$6
  21 - SEL$6C998BA3 / ACC@SEL$7
  22 - SEL$6C998BA3 / ACC@SEL$7
  23 - SEL$6C998BA3 / SCT@SEL$8
  24 - SEL$6C998BA3 / SCT@SEL$8
  25 - SEL$6C998BA3 / LST@SEL$9
  26 - SEL$6C998BA3 / EM@SEL$6
  27 - SEL$6C998BA3 / EM@SEL$6
  28 - SEL$6C998BA3 / SPT@SEL$10
  29 - SEL$6C998BA3 / SPT@SEL$10

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_ID"="LST"."SOLD_COMPONENT_FK")
   3 - access("SPT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_ID"="SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK")
   4 - access("SCT"."ACCOUNT_FK"="ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID")
   5 - access("ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID"="LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK")
   6 - access("EM"."ACCOUNT_FK"="LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK")
   7 - filter(TO_NUMBER("EM"."EXT_ID_TYPE_CODE_ID")=2 AND 
              TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("EM"."VALID_FROM"))<SYSDATE@!)
   8 - filter("LAT"."RECORD_STATE_IND"=0 AND "LAT"."LC_STATE"='ACT')
  10 - filter("SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_TYPE"='UTF')
  11 - filter("SPT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_NAME" LIKE 'T_%')
  12 - filter("LST"."RECORD_STATE_IND"=0 AND "LST"."LC_STATE"='ACT')
  16 - access("SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_ID"="LST"."SOLD_COMPONENT_FK")
  20 - filter("LAT"."LC_SUB_STATE_CODE_ID"='LOST' AND "LAT"."RECORD_STATE_IND"=0 AND 
              "LAT"."LC_STATE"='PAS')
  22 - access("ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID"="LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK")
  23 - access("SCT"."ACCOUNT_FK"="ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID")
  24 - filter("SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_TYPE"='UTF')
  25 - filter("LST"."LC_STATE"='PAS' AND "LST"."RECORD_STATE_IND"=0 AND 
              "LST"."LC_SUB_STATE_CODE_ID"='STD')
  26 - filter(TO_NUMBER("EM"."EXT_ID_TYPE_CODE_ID")=2 AND 
              TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("EM"."VALID_FROM"))<SYSDATE@!)
  27 - access("EM"."ACCOUNT_FK"="LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK")
  28 - access("SPT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_ID"="SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK")
  29 - filter("SPT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_NAME" LIKE 'T_%')

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------

   1 - STRDEF[113]
   2 - (#keys=1) "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32], 
       "SPT"."PROD_CODE_ID"[NUMBER,22]
   3 - (#keys=1) "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "SPT"."PROD_CODE_ID"[NUMBER,22]
   4 - (#keys=1) "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
   5 - (#keys=1) "ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32], 
       "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13]
   6 - (#keys=1) "LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32]
   7 - "EM"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32]
   8 - "LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
   9 - "ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13]
  10 - "SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "SCT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
  11 - "SPT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "SPT"."PROD_CODE_ID"[NUMBER,22]
  12 - "LST"."SOLD_COMPONENT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
  13 - (#keys=0) "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "SCT"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32], 
       "SPT"."PROD_CODE_ID"[NUMBER,22]
  14 - (#keys=0) "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "SCT"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32], "SPT".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  15 - (#keys=0) "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "SCT"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32]
  16 - (#keys=1) "LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "SCT"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13]
  17 - (#keys=0) "LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "SCT"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
  18 - (#keys=0) "LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "SCT".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  19 - (#keys=0) "LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID"[NUMBER,22], 
       "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13]
  20 - "LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
  21 - "ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13]
  22 - "ACC".ROWID[ROWID,10], "ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID"[NUMBER,22]
  23 - "SCT".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  24 - "SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "SCT"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
  25 - "LST"."SOLD_COMPONENT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
  26 - "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32]
  27 - "EM".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  28 - "SPT".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  29 - "SPT"."PROD_CODE_ID"[NUMBER,22]
```

Which runs decently.

Now when I replace all `||'|'||` with commas to keep the columns separate, Oracle factorizes the join with `SOLD_PRODUCT_TBL` out of the `UNION ALL` resulting in this execution plan:

```
Plan hash value: 646317754

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                       | 11287 |   815K| 35502   (2)| 00:08:18 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                           |                       | 11287 |   815K| 35502   (2)| 00:08:18 |
|   2 |   VIEW                               | VW_JF_SET$384100DE    | 11287 |   540K| 34081   (2)| 00:07:58 |
|   3 |    UNION-ALL                         |                       |       |       |            |          |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN                        |                       | 11274 |  1134K| 22876   (2)| 00:05:21 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN                       |                       |  9778 |   859K| 15871   (2)| 00:03:43 |
|*  6 |       HASH JOIN                      |                       | 19744 |  1311K|  9871   (2)| 00:02:19 |
|*  7 |        HASH JOIN                     |                       | 19744 |   944K|  5143   (2)| 00:01:12 |
|*  8 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL            | EVENT_MAPPING_TBL     | 17199 |   604K|  1309   (4)| 00:00:19 |
|*  9 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL            | LC_ACCOUNT_TBL        |   259K|  3291K|  3832   (1)| 00:00:54 |
|  10 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL             | ACCOUNT_TBL           |   689K|    12M|  4724   (1)| 00:01:07 |
|* 11 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL              | SOLD_COMPONENT_TBL    |   341K|  7339K|  5998   (1)| 00:01:24 |
|* 12 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL               | LC_SOLD_COMPONENT_TBL |   855K|    10M|  7001   (2)| 00:01:39 |
|  13 |     NESTED LOOPS                     |                       |    13 |  1638 | 11205   (1)| 00:02:37 |
|  14 |      NESTED LOOPS                    |                       |    26 |  1638 | 11205   (1)| 00:02:37 |
|* 15 |       HASH JOIN                      |                       |    13 |  1170 | 11179   (1)| 00:02:37 |
|  16 |        NESTED LOOPS                  |                       |    43 |  3096 |  4179   (1)| 00:00:59 |
|  17 |         NESTED LOOPS                 |                       |   435 |  3096 |  4179   (1)| 00:00:59 |
|  18 |          NESTED LOOPS                |                       |    87 |  3219 |  3920   (1)| 00:00:55 |
|* 19 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL          | LC_ACCOUNT_TBL        |    87 |  1566 |  3833   (2)| 00:00:54 |
|  20 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| ACCOUNT_TBL           |     1 |    19 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 21 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | ACCOUNT_PK            |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN            | SC_ACCFK_IDX          |     5 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 23 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | SOLD_COMPONENT_TBL    |     1 |    35 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 24 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL             | LC_SOLD_COMPONENT_TBL |   101K|  1778K|  6999   (1)| 00:01:38 |
|* 25 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN               | EM_ACCFK_IDX          |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 26 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | EVENT_MAPPING_TBL     |     1 |    36 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 27 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | SOLD_PRODUCT_TBL      |   345K|  8442K|  1419   (2)| 00:00:20 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$13BCA951
   2 - SET$384100DE / VW_JF_SET$384100DE@SEL$135D31FF
   3 - SET$384100DE
   4 - SEL$3A68C552
   8 - SEL$3A68C552 / EM@SEL$1
   9 - SEL$3A68C552 / LAT@SEL$1
  10 - SEL$3A68C552 / ACC@SEL$2
  11 - SEL$3A68C552 / SCT@SEL$3
  12 - SEL$3A68C552 / LST@SEL$5
  13 - SEL$6EF128F5
  19 - SEL$6EF128F5 / LAT@SEL$6
  20 - SEL$6EF128F5 / ACC@SEL$7
  21 - SEL$6EF128F5 / ACC@SEL$7
  22 - SEL$6EF128F5 / SCT@SEL$8
  23 - SEL$6EF128F5 / SCT@SEL$8
  24 - SEL$6EF128F5 / LST@SEL$9
  25 - SEL$6EF128F5 / EM@SEL$6
  26 - SEL$6EF128F5 / EM@SEL$6
  27 - SEL$13BCA951 / SPT@SEL$4

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("SPT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_ID"="ITEM_1")
   4 - access("SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_ID"="LST"."SOLD_COMPONENT_FK")
   5 - access("SCT"."ACCOUNT_FK"="ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID")
   6 - access("ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID"="LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK")
   7 - access("EM"."ACCOUNT_FK"="LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK")
   8 - filter(TO_NUMBER("EM"."EXT_ID_TYPE_CODE_ID")=2 AND 
              TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("EM"."VALID_FROM"))<SYSDATE@!)
   9 - filter("LAT"."RECORD_STATE_IND"=0 AND "LAT"."LC_STATE"='ACT')
  11 - filter("SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_TYPE"='UTF')
  12 - filter("LST"."RECORD_STATE_IND"=0 AND "LST"."LC_STATE"='ACT')
  15 - access("SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_ID"="LST"."SOLD_COMPONENT_FK")
  19 - filter("LAT"."LC_SUB_STATE_CODE_ID"='LOST' AND "LAT"."RECORD_STATE_IND"=0 AND 
              "LAT"."LC_STATE"='PAS')
  21 - access("ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID"="LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK")
  22 - access("SCT"."ACCOUNT_FK"="ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID")
  23 - filter("SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_TYPE"='UTF')
  24 - filter("LST"."LC_STATE"='PAS' AND "LST"."RECORD_STATE_IND"=0 AND 
              "LST"."LC_SUB_STATE_CODE_ID"='STD')
  25 - access("EM"."ACCOUNT_FK"="LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK")
  26 - filter(TO_NUMBER("EM"."EXT_ID_TYPE_CODE_ID")=2 AND 
              TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("EM"."VALID_FROM"))<SYSDATE@!)
  27 - filter("SPT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_NAME" LIKE 'T_%')

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------

   1 - (#keys=1) "ITEM_4"[DATE,7], "ITEM_2"[VARCHAR2,32], "ITEM_3"[DATE,7], 
       "SPT"."PROD_CODE_ID"[NUMBER,22]
   2 - "ITEM_1"[NUMBER,22], "ITEM_2"[VARCHAR2,32], "ITEM_3"[DATE,7], "ITEM_4"[DATE,7]
   3 - STRDEF[22], STRDEF[32], STRDEF[7], STRDEF[7]
   4 - (#keys=1) "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
   5 - (#keys=1) "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
   6 - (#keys=1) "ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32], 
       "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13]
   7 - (#keys=1) "LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32]
   8 - "EM"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32]
   9 - "LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
  10 - "ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13]
  11 - "SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "SCT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
  12 - "LST"."SOLD_COMPONENT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
  13 - (#keys=0) "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "SCT"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32]
  14 - (#keys=0) "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "SCT"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "EM".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  15 - (#keys=1) "LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "SCT"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13]
  16 - (#keys=0) "LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "SCT"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
  17 - (#keys=0) "LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "SCT".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  18 - (#keys=0) "LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22], "ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID"[NUMBER,22], 
       "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13]
  19 - "LAT"."ACCOUNT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
  20 - "ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "ACC"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13]
  21 - "ACC".ROWID[ROWID,10], "ACC"."ACCOUNT_ID"[NUMBER,22]
  22 - "SCT".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  23 - "SCT"."SOLD_COMPONENT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "SCT"."FIRST_ACT_DATE"[TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,13], 
       "SCT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
  24 - "LST"."SOLD_COMPONENT_FK"[NUMBER,22]
  25 - "EM".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  26 - "EM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,32]
  27 - "SPT"."SOLD_PRODUCT_ID"[NUMBER,22], "SPT"."PROD_CODE_ID"[NUMBER,22]
```

Which, to put it mildly, sucks golf balls through garden hoses; it appears to execute immediately, then the client spends 17 minutes "Fetching" the first few rows.

***Why?*** `/*+ NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION */` prevents this but I'm still puzzled by how column projection can influence a join.

Comment: As another potential work-around, what happens if you include both the original columns and the concatenation?

Comment: @Colin'tHart: yes, including the concatenated column along with the original ones prevents the factorization; any expression with two columns like `acc.first_act_date - sct.first_act_date`, will have that effect, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

The database checks the possibility of the same transformation on the 1st version too, but it seems the concatenated columns prevent the usage of Join Factorization. "It seems", because I could not find any reference to this, as it is vaguely documented, just tested it myself on 11.2.0.4.

```
create table t1 as select * from all_objects;
create table t2 as select * from all_objects;
create index t1_ind1 on t1(owner);
create index t1_ind2 on t1(object_type);

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user,'T1',
        method_opt=>'for all indexed columns size 254');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user,'T2',
        method_opt=>'for all indexed columns size 254');        
end;
/
```

And the 2 queries:

```
select t1.owner, t1.object_name
from t1, t2
where t1.object_id = t2.object_id
and t1.owner ='SCOTT'
union all
select t1.owner, t1.object_name
from t1, t2
where t1.object_id = t2.object_id
and t1.object_type ='VIEW'
/

select t1.owner || t1.object_name
from t1, t2
where t1.object_id = t2.object_id
and t1.owner ='SCOTT'
union all
select t1.owner || t1.object_name
from t1, t2
where t1.object_id = t2.object_id
and t1.object_type ='VIEW'
/
```

The database uses Join Factorization in the 1st one, but not in the 2nd one. Below are some excerpts from the optimizer traces:

```
JF: Checking validity of join factorization for query block SEL$1 (#0)
JF: Bypassed: not a UNION or UNION-ALL query block.
JF: Checking validity of join factorization for query block SEL$2 (#0)
JF: Bypassed: not a UNION or UNION-ALL query block.
JF: Checking validity of join factorization for query block SET$1 (#0)
JF: Checking validity of join factorization for query block SEL$1 (#3)
JF: Bypassed: not a UNION or UNION-ALL query block.
JF: Checking validity of join factorization for query block SEL$2 (#2)
JF: Bypassed: not a UNION or UNION-ALL query block.
JF: Checking validity of join factorization for query block SET$1 (#1)
JF: Using search type: exhaustive
JF: Checking validity of join factorization for query block SET$1 (#1)
JF: Generate basic transformation units
JF: unit inserted into state space: (branch: {2, 3} table: {T2, T2})
JF: Generate transformation units from basic units
JF: Starting iteration 1, state space = {}
JF: Transformed query
JF: Costing transformed query.
JF: Updated best state, Cost = 161.69
JF: Starting iteration 2, state space = {(branch: {2, 3} table: {T2, T2})}
JF: Transformed query
JF: Costing transformed query.
JF: Updated best state, Cost = 109.90
JF:   Transferring best state space to preseved query.
JF:   Transferring best state space to original query.
```

This is for the 1st query, the database calculates the cost of the transformations, then later decides to use it (did not post everything, as that would be much more than the above).

Now for the 2nd query, this is what the optimizer did:

```
JF: Checking validity of join factorization for query block SEL$1 (#0)
JF: Bypassed: not a UNION or UNION-ALL query block.
JF: Checking validity of join factorization for query block SEL$2 (#0)
JF: Bypassed: not a UNION or UNION-ALL query block.
JF: Checking validity of join factorization for query block SET$1 (#0)
JF: Bypassed: Not more than one branch has JF optimization opportunity.
JF: Checking validity of join factorization for query block SEL$1 (#0)
JF: Bypassed: not a UNION or UNION-ALL query block.
JF: Checking validity of join factorization for query block SEL$2 (#0)
JF: Bypassed: not a UNION or UNION-ALL query block.
JF: Checking validity of join factorization for query block SET$1 (#0)
JF: Bypassed: Not more than one branch has JF optimization opportunity.
```

It bypassed JF on all possible places (note the different decision at query block SET$1), and that is it. It did not consider using JF at all.

As to why the 2nd one is slower, well, the optimizer works with statistics, those statistics may be inaccurate, but even if they are a 100% accurate, it can still just estimate the cost based on them, and sometimes it makes mistakes.

Comment: Yes, apparently any expression involving two columns will prevent this type of transformation (I'm also running 11.2.0.4.0). And I do have some stale stats; I just emailed the DBAs about it. Thanks for the test!